# How to IMPORT Enterprise Vault Archive Mails back to Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange

We want to get rid of the Symantec EV for Email. How to import back the emails back to Exchange 2007? Do we need another tool or EV have it's own?

Comment: Are you asking as a user, or as a system administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Bongie,
You can use the Export function within Enterprise Vault to export the contents of the archive back to the original location in the mailbox.  There are also third party companies that have utilities to perform this operation.
http://www.symantec.com/theme.jsp?themeid=enterprise-vault-extensions